# Вызов функции C#

Tags: c#, winforms, функции

Добрый день. Не могу разобраться. В проге написал функцию замены 2-х переменных:

```
 static public void change(int x, int y)
    {
        int buff = x;
        x = y;
        y = buff;
    }
```

Далее, в теле программы по нажатии на кнопку:

```
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        int y = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
        change(x, y);
        label1.Text = x.ToString();
        label2.Text = y.ToString();
```

Трассирую, функция вызывается, в ней переменные меняются местами, а вот потом, в теле нажатия кнопки - остаются прежними. Т.е.,грубо говоря, функция не передала значение. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
static public void change(ref int x,ref int y)
{
    int buff = x;
    x = y;
    y = buff;
}
int x = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    int y = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
    change(ref x,ref y);
    label1.Text = x.ToString();
    label2.Text = y.ToString();
```

Answer (score 6):

Вы меняете значения копий, а не переменных. Почитайте про ключевые слова out и ref

Comment: и про различия value-типов (структур) от reference-типов (классов)

Comment: да-да, обязательно